# How to do an unsecure fetch from Next.js api handler?

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js app that communicated with an old microservice that doesn't have TLS. I wrote an API handler to query this microservice using HTTP but when I tried to fetch Nextjs blocks it saying (basically) "no unsecured fetches from backend in prod". While I agree with this sentiment I still need this to work.

I tried deploying a second instance of my Nextjs app in dev mode to my cluster, but that didn't work because of an issue with auth0. Altering the microservice is incredibly impractical. I need Nextjs to do the unsecure fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce some reverse proxy with the TLS termination in front of the microservice.

How to achieve that will depend on the infrastructure you're using.